# MpAndroidChart HorizontalBarChart labels

Tags: mpandroidchart

I am using HorizontalBarChart in my app. Is it possible to move the labels of the graph to the left insead of right (default position)?

Thanks.

Comment: In the dataset where I have the information to show I have setted the Axis to left with the following instruction, but it is not working. It is showing the values at right position. setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);

Comment: Hey @Nits_ , I want to do the same. Did you manage to do it?

Comment: Yes i did it, You need to get the Legend of the graph that you are using and then you can set the Position of the Legend.

Legend l = graph.getLegend();
l.setPosition(Legend.LegendPosition.LEFT_OF_CHART_CENTER);

HTH.

Comment: Hey @Nits_ , Could you check the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38975333/mpandroidchart-horizontalbarchart-customize-label

Comment: Oh sorry, I understood you now. I think that is not possible but you can always ask to @PhillipJahoda. Maybe in the next version of the library he can do it...